# The last event called after page loaded

Tags: c#, .net

Because I don't want to use the SessionState I created a small layer myself that acts like Session and retrieves and stores the values in a database. Once retrieved the values this is stored in a static dictionary with a unique identifier per visitor (*HttpContext.Current.Request.AnonymousID*).

The problem I have now is that I don't know when to store the currently changed values and clear the *'session'* in the dictionary for that user. If I wouldn't clear it the database and frontend values can become dissimilar.

So I thought using the *page_unload event*, but that event is called multiple times (probably because controls inside the page?) so this would cause unnecessary reloading the data from the database again if another control needs the data.

Is there a way to execute a method that is only executed once when the page and controls are rendered, the last event called?

Comment: I wonder what's wrong with SessionState. I'm feeling you're reinventing the wheel

Comment: SessionState blocks parallel execution and forces parallel requests to be executed one after another.

Comment: "The problem I have now is that I don't know when to store the currently changed values and clear the 'session' in the dictionary for that user" - This sounds like a specification problem not a coding problem. When do you want to update the values? Why are they getting stale? As for the question ActionFilterAttributes provide some hooks that would be useful if you are using MVC - there is an event for after the results have finished running.

Comment: As far as I know the page_Unload is called once. I had a problem when the page was loaded multiple times (this would cause the page_unload to be called multiple times too) and the problem was error 404 on some of the links. These caused my page to load multiple times. Currently I do error checking and sending of email to Developers at MasterPage's page_unload and it runs once.

Comment: - SollyM got that to work now, tnx
- @SteveB know any alternative?
- Chris I know when I want to store the data (after everything is loaded), but wasn't able to find the right solution/event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added my comment as an answer so that you can mark it as relevant and can help someone else in the future.

> As far as I know the `page_unload` is called once. I had a problem when
>   the page was loaded multiple times (this would cause the `page_unload`
>   to be called multiple times too) and the problem was `error 404` on some
>   of the links. These caused my page to load multiple times. Currently I
>   do error checking and sending of email to Developers at MasterPage's
>   `page_unload` and it runs once.